# use client to connect to mysql inside a docker network

Tags: mysql, docker, client

I'm using docker swarm to create a small infrastructure with different wordpress instances, I have an ingress (nginx) and different stacks (wp,mysql,wp). The docker-compose for each stack is like this:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  foo-frontend:
  foo-backend:

volumes:
  db_data:
  wordpress_data:

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - db.env
    networks:
      - foo-backend
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html/wp-content
    env_file:
      - wp.env
    networks:
      - foo-frontend
      - foo-backend

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - foo-frontend
```

while the ingress is:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ~/docker-vps/ingress/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - foo-frontend

networks:
  frontend:
    external: true
```

my problem is that I'm not able to connect to mysql with my client, I tried to use the container ip with the right port but is not working....is there a way to connect to mysql with a client?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider as hostname the name of service. This is how services communicate. So, the hostname of database is `db`. Let me know the error message that occurs, because I don't have rating to comment your original question to know this.

Comment: the hostname is `db` inside the networks, but outside? I'm not sure it is the same because in that case I should get some conflict as all the other stack has the same services names (only the nginx service has different names)....I think the main problem is to find the the right hostname of the db....I tried to use the container ip:
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'  XXX  => 10.0.123.3 and then telnet 10.0.123.3 3306 but is not available

Comment: What's the content of wp.env and db.env?

Comment: env variables for db init and wp

Comment: I'm asking about the values ... can I see them?